# Removing Question Mark and Equal Sign from URL php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

This may be a duplicate but I have looked all over with no success and I have a website where a person enters a string into the `$_GET` of the URL (i.e. `/index.php?w=string`)

And I have my `$string = _GET['w']` variable

But my question is I want to know if it is possible to rewrite the .htaccess file so that it will display instead of `/index.php?w=string` to just `/string` and then the `$string` variable can still be filled with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this in your **`.htaccess`** file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?w=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That would allow you to access the url like: `http://www.example.com/string`

Thus allowing you to access your **`$_GET['w']`** and display the relevant page/content however you please with some SEO friendly URL's.

### More Reading

[URL Rewrite for beginners..](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

[Introduction to URL Rewriting](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting-2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
^/(.*)$ /index.php?w=$1
```